# How to find this limit given only a derivative in a point?

Tags: calculus, limits

Given that
$f(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(0)=1$, 
I'm trying to find $$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac {f(x^2)-f(0)}{\sin^2(x)}
$$

I feel like I should try and use Tailor to make the denominator more usable but that's no good because $f(x)$ is only differentiable once.

How best to approach this problem?

Comment: Rewrite as $\frac{x^2}{sin^2 x}\frac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{x^2}$ and it's almost over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac {f(x^2)-f(0)}{\sin^2(x)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac {f(x^2)-f(0)}{x^2-0}\cdot\dfrac1{\left(\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^2}$$

Now $g'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{g(x+h)-f(x)}h$